# delay in wicket component tooltip

Tags: java, tooltip, wicket, textfield

I am using `tool tip` in wicket.It shows by delay and I couldn't speed it up.I want to make some css attributes for it . How can I do?

```
inputTextField.add(AttributeModifier.append("title", "I am a tool tip in wicket"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style-attribute can be added the same way you used the AttributeModifier for the title-attribute.

```
inputTextField.add(new AttributeAppender("style", Model.of("border: 1px solid red;")));
```

But I think this will not solve your "delay problem" (it is not Wicket related). You could pick a decent JavaScript library that draws you tooltip boxes on mouse over.

There are also pure CSS tooltip libraries, for example: [hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/)

Comment: Thank you so much sedden.It was helpful.I downloaded hint.css and I am going to use client side methods to do so

Comment: sedden using client side programming for such issues is recommended?one of the most powers of wicket is to reducing the code in client side part.I may have no other choices!!

Comment: You could use Behaviors to extend your markup automatically (add another _div_ before or after the component, add style attributes, ... ).